# Binding IsEnabled to IsChecked in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've CheckBox and RadioButton. I need bind IsEnabled property to IsChecked property

```
<CheckBox x:Name="check_box" Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="True" />

<RadioButton Content="Depending Component" IsChecked="True" Margin="15,3,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding check_box.IsChecked}" />
```

Is there any way to do it without the code writing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an **ElementName** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname(v=vs.110).aspx)) binding:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="check_box" Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="True" />
<RadioButton IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=check_box, Path=IsChecked, 
                                 TargetNullValue=false}" .../>
```

Comment: `IsChecked` is `Nullable<bool>`-typed, so ideally the binding should set some `TargetNullValue`, e.g., `False`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I had no idea you could specify that; what a cool feature! Added to my answer, and thank you for the info.